# Node project: trying to use the same ES6 code for both the front end and back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a need to share front end and back end code in a single javascript project. The front end code is transpiled using babel and the back end code is a node script (not a web app) that runs on the server.

There's currently just a single package.json file in the project.

I'm using --experimental-vm-modules to run the node server script which allows me to use ES6 syntax and import statements, however it requires the javascript files to have an .mjs extension.

The catch-22 I'm running into is that the file that is meant to be shared between the FE and BE (sharedConstants.js) only works on the back end with an .mjs extension and only works on the client side with a .js extension.

Another solution I considered was to put 'type: module' in package.json file, but then this breaks the compilation of the client side app which uses webpack, babel, react, etc.

The project is currently using node version v14.18.0 but I'm open to considering an upgrade if that in some way helps to resolve this issue.

UPDATE:
Webpack version is 4.42.0 and @babel/core version is 7.2.2
(also added contents of .babelrc, webpack.config.babel.js and webpack.config.common.js)

Contents of .babelrc:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "antd"],
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "antd-mobile"],
    ["babel-plugin-webpack-alias", { "config": "./webpack.config.common.js" }]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "only": [
    "./**/*.js",
    "node_modules/jest-runtime"
  ],
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Contents of webpack.config.babel.js:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let webpackCommon = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = Object.assign({}, webpackCommon, {
  mode: 'development',

  entry: [
    './src/app-client.js',
    /* The port on the development server must be entered in this section to
       work properly. */
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:4000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
  ],

  output: {
    // Files are being written to disk so it's not certain at this point if
    // they are being served from memory in a development environment.
    // TODO: Confirm the performance impact of disk vs memory and if with the
    //       current configuration the files are being served from memory.
    path: __dirname + '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',

  // dev server settings
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './public/index-static.html',
    /* all requests are proxied to receive the response,
    if it is bundle file, program uses script of dev server. */
    proxy: {
      '**': 'http://localhost:5000' // express server address
    },
    stats: {
      // minimize console log
      assets: false,
      colors: true,
      version: false,
      hash: false,
      timings: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }
  }
});

module.exports.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
```

Contents of webpack.config.common.js:

```
// Common webpack configuration.

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js');
const antdThemeVarsOverride = lessToJs(
  fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, './src/static/less/antd-theme-vars-override.less'),
    'utf8'
  )
);
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/app-client.js', './src/static/less/main.less'],

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    // NOTE! If you change the order of the rules, the end of the prod
    // webpack config file must be changed as well!
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {loader: 'react-hot-loader/webpack'},
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: JSON.stringify({
              babelrc: false,
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
              plugins: [
                '@babel/transform-runtime',
                '@babel/proposal-class-properties',
                'lodash',
                ['import', {libraryName: 'antd', style: true}, 'antd'],
                [
                  'import',
                  {libraryName: 'antd-mobile', style: true},
                  'antd-mobile'
                ]
              ]
            })
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.modernizrrc.js$/,
        use: ['modernizr-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.modernizrrc(\.json)?$/,
        use: ['modernizr-loader', 'json-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              modifyVars: antdThemeVarsOverride,
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
    alias: {
      Actions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/actions/'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      Containers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers/'),
      Db: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server/db/'),
      Table: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/HipocampoTable/'),
      Js: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/'),
      Layouts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/layouts/'),
      Reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/reducers/'),
      Selectors: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/selectors/'),
      Server: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server/'),
      Scripts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts/'),
      Spreadsheets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'spreadsheets/'),
      Shared: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/'),
      Slices: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/slices/'),
      Static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/static/'),
      Support: path.resolve(__dirname, 'cypress/support/'),
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, '.modernizrrc')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.less', '.jsx', '.css', '.sql']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from: './static/favicon.png', to: 'favicon.png'},
        {from: './static/circle_logo.png', to: 'circle_logo.png'}
      ]
    }),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Hipocampo',
      template: './static/index-template.html',
      filename: 'index-static.html',
      // This is needed to ensure that the password reset link works.
      publicPath: '/',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: false,
        removeComments: false
      }
    }),
    // This is to reduce the moment.js webpack size
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en-US/),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: `--experimental-vm-modules ` is only required for Node 12. Node 14 and 16 support ESM based on `"type": "module` in the package.json file, without caring about file extensions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OP does mention that in the question.

Comment: They mention they are using node 14, so they shouldn't need that flag.

Comment: I rather doubt people can help without seeing a lot more specifics (code, configurations, etc...).   You should be able to use a `"type": "module"` ESM module file in both client and server with  the proper configuration.

Comment: But if I put "type": "module" in the package.json file, it breaks the webpack/babel compilation of the front end code.

Comment: If you're using ESM, I can recommend using `esbuild` instead of webpack+babel (it's both less tooling, and incredibly much faster). But if you have to stick with webpack+babel, make sure you're using new enough versions (so please [mention which ones you're using in your post](/help/how-to-ask), and explain how you configured them. Definitely show [mcve] code)

Comment: Well, that's because your webpack configuration apparently needs fixing.  Webpack can handle [ESM modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/ecma-script-modules/) if you do things correctly.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when I originally wrote the question, it hadn't occurred to me that the potential fix would be through webpack (or a substitution) so I didn't include the version. The question has been updated with the babel and webpack versions

Comment: What would be a reason to have the same `package.json` for frontend and backend? You can have one project with two subprojects and two different `package.json`.

Comment: @jabaa It's not a requirement to have one package.json file. This project is a monorepo and up until now (perhaps this is about to change) there's never been a need to have two separate files for FE and BE.

Comment: webpack 4.42 is over 2 years old at this point, so the first thing to try would be to use webpack 5 instead and see if that solves your problem (and then you'll want to give https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5 a read). Or give esbuild a try (because now would be the perfect opportunity for it)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to use the same file for both the back end and the front end, and ended up adding a transform to the webpack config to create an .mjs file from the .js file:

```
        {
      dest: './src/shared/sharedUtils.mjs',
      src: './src/shared/sharedUtils.js',
      transforms: {
        before: async (code) => {
          code = code.replace('sharedConstants.js', 'sharedConstants.mjs');
          code =
            '// This file is generated dynamically' +
            ' from sharedUtils.js\n' +
            code;
          code = '// !!DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY!!\n' + code;
          return code;
        }
      }
    }
```